# "shop by" box / layered navigation not showing

Tags: layered-navigation

How can I make the layered navigation to appear on my site home page ( or any other pages)

I have a default category and a laptop category with “is anchor” set to YES.

These categories contains products with price.

The attribute price is set as filterable.

I still see no layered navigation appearing. What can be missing?

Comment: have you tried using other filterable attributes likes color and such? are you using flat tables for categories and products? (I don't know if it impacts the layered navigation though)

Comment: by other pages to you mean other cms pages or search results/category pages.

Comment: Using a dropdown attribute (color) that i have set to filterable, the 'shop by box' appeared in results/category pages. I dont know why prices do not appear

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure how your homepage is configured, but by default you can't make it happen.

Try adding a Category block on your homepage, by adding

`{{block type="catalog/product_list" category_id="8" template="catalog/product/list.phtml"}}`

on you Homepage CMS's page content. Replace category_id with your category's id.

Cheers.